# Problem connecting to localhost PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

When I try to connect to a small localhost PostGIS database using QGIS, I get the error message:

FATAL: no pg_hba.conf for host "fe80::4528:3236:418a9e7b%10" user "postgres", database "nyc", SSL off

The file pg_hba.conf contains

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

I can connect just fine using pgAdmin. I noticed that a few others have asked similar questions here, but I can´t find a solution using localhost. Any suggestions on what to try? QGIS 1.8.0 and PostgreSQL 9.2/PostGIS 2 on Win Vista 64 bit.

[image: PostGIS Connection]

Comment: Is "fe80::4528:3236:418a9e7b%10" really the name of the host? What have you specified as connection parameters? On Windows 7, I can even let the host name free, giving only port, database name and username.

Comment: Is postgres actually serving on port 5432 (the default)?

Comment: In my configuration, I have Dator=localhost, checked 'public' schema and Use estimated table metadata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the database runs on localhost, you should specify localhost in the Host field which seems to be called "Dator" in your screenshot.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That helped. Why didn´t I try that before?