# Can't connect to WMS service? An Amazon-EC2 problem?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, windows, amazon-ec2

I'm running GeoServer 2.3.5 on a Windows instance in AWS for the first time.  The data is on the server in PostGIS.  The map layers have been published and I can see them locally without any problems.  However, when I try to access the WMS service for these layers from another machine, I can't connect.  I'm wondering if there is some configuration I may be missing because this is set up through AWS.  Any ideas?

Comment: check the pg_hba.conf for postgis needs to be modified to give the correct permissions http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Any examples on what the format may look like? The file suggests adding more "host" records to allow non-local interfaces. In other words, just the user just be "all" and the address be infinite?

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50194/problem-connecting-to-localhost-postgis

Comment: do you see any messages in the browser when you try to connect? or in the GeoServer log?